# Unable to login with user that I created in sql database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, localdb

I'm trying to connect with my DB using a account that I created with db_owner rights. Windows authentication  works but not sql server authentication

I can confirm that the role was created as there is a error message login failed for user when using a wrong password. Compared to when correct password.

My local db is created in ASP.net web application by simply adding a local db in App data.

Error message is

> user guest does not have permission to run DBCC checkpriamry file.

User has been created using

```
CREATE LOGIN [SomeUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'topsecret';
CREATE USER [SomeUser] FOR LOGIN [SomeUser];
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'SomeUser'
```

EDIT:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Shop" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Shop.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BsqV.jpg

are the links of error message

Comment: It appears you are connecting using the guest account and not the SomeUser account.  What does your connection string look like?

Comment: @JM_ i have posted it

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the user in the database you have in your connection string?

Comment: @Bosco Yes I'm absolutely sure that the user exists

Comment: You need to set Integrated Security=False in order for it to use the credentials in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string when define login must be like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Shop" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Shop.mdf;Initial Catalog=Shop.mdf;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=SomeUser; Password=topsecret;"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: It does not work.  Please refer to my edit above for the error message

Comment: Ensure that the login account has at least CREATE DATABASE, CREATE ANY DATABASE, or ALTER ANY DATABASE permission. You could grant the fixed server role 'dbcreator' or 'sysadmin' to the login account

Comment: this link maybe help you : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/341d48f1-9826-4a5c-a9cc-50a3453ca01d/user-guest-does-not-have-permission-to-run-dbcc?forum=sqlgetstarted